# htaccess not redirecting to my dynamic filtered page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

At present I have a dynamic page showing its correct content when I have the url

```
m.mysite.com/bakery.php?yum=5
```

the page is above is passed a variable `yum=5` to filter it and shows the content for cakes (aka `yum=6` is for wedding cakes)

but I want the above `m.mysite.com/bakery.php?yum=5` to appear as `m.mysite.com/cakes.php`

I have done some htaccess testing as I can show you below

I use the pages `cakes.php` and `bread.php` to be sure that my syntax was correct.

```
Redirect 301 /cakes.php /bread.php
```

above works both ways no problem aka you enter `cakes.php` into the url and it takes you very fast to `bread.php`

```
Redirect 301 /bread.php /cakes.php
```

above works both ways no problem aka you enter `bread.php` into the url and it takes you very fast to `cakes.php`

```
Redirect 301 /bakery.php?yum=5 http://m.mysite.com/cakes.php
```

above shows the `/bakery.php?yum=5` page when requested and the `cakes.php` page when requested both do not do any redir

```
Redirect 301 cakes.php /bakery.php?yum=5
```

above shows the `/bakery.php?yum=5` page when `cakes.php` is requested

Can anyone please tell me as to why when `cakes.php` is requested i am not showed the contents of `/bakery.php?yum=5`

```
Redirect 301 /bakery.php?yum=5 cakes.php
```

above shows the `/bakery.php?yum=5` page when `cakes.php` is requested

I want to know why when `cakes.php` is requested i am not showed the contents of     `/bakery.php?yum=5`, aka I want to go to the page `cakes.php` and see content for it.

Comment: please post your complete htaccess file

Comment: You can't use `Redirect` to redirect a URL with a query string. It won't match.

Comment: Google is your friend - be not afraid:  https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect a URL like this with a query string you can use Rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^yum=5$
RewriteRule ^bakery\.php$ /cakes.php? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: http://goo.gl/2lyUTq    <<< it gives me a 404

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fabrictype=27$
RewriteRule ^fabrictypes\.php$ /velvets.php? [R=301,L]


this one is without the redirect
http://goo.gl/O15UPB

could it be due to the site been m.site.com aka specifially for mobile

Comment: It gives 404 not found because that file is not really there. If I just type in `http://m.londonfabriccompany.com/velvets.php` it gives 404. The actual file has to exist on mobile site too or you will have to use the full URL to the main domain. in the rule. `RewriteRule ^fabrictypes\.php$ http://domain.com/velvets.php? [R=301,L]`

Comment: thank you very much for your patience. 
and excuse my ignorance. velvets.php is not really a page. I was under the belief that 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fabrictype=27$
RewriteRule ^fabrictypes\.php$ http://m.londonfabriccompany.com/velvets.php? [R=301,L]

when a user gets to the fabrictypes page and it is filtered like it is..... then the page just gets renamed.

I have tried what you mentioned below only to get a 404

`code` RewriteRule ^fabrictypes\.php$ http://m.londonfabriccompany.com/velvets.php? [R=301,L]

Comment: What do you mean `then the page just gets renamed`? You need to redirect to a real page regardless of using the full domain or relative path.

Comment: /fabrictypes.php?fabrictype=5 <<< that works and filters the db but I do not want anyone to see that /fabrictypes.php?fabrictype=5...... I prefer them to see a page specific called ontract.php for that record. thus /fabrictypes.php?fabrictype=6 is a different record and I would want them to see a page specific record for that in a page call cotton.php..... over all there are about 200 pages but rather then having to create 200 pages I have the them to see a page specific called ontract.php for that record. thus    /fabrictypes.php?fabrictype=  filter the db